# Rails App Backend (separate from frontend?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m still learning a lot about Rails and looking for some guidance on the best way to setup an admin section. My main tool (and that of people I will be developing for) over the past few years has been WordPress, so I’m looking to make something similar to the Dashboard.

Does anyone know of a guide, or able to provide some quick tips on the easiest way to do setup something like site.com/admin that would have the CMS functionality, and site.com would just display the content? I imagine with Routes and Views, but I’m not sure where to jump in.

I understand there’s ActiveAdmin etc, but I’m doing this as an education piece to begin. I figure it’s a really good way to learn more about how apps are built.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I now seem to have things working to some extent with a namespace, but I'm having trouble getting the views setup.

controllers/admin/application_controller.rb

`class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

Now I'm confused as to where to put my views, specifically the partials and application.html.erb in /layouts. It would be logical for these to go in views/admin/layouts, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is anyone able to provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa. I recommend `rails new`ing a sample project and install that gem. Then you can see how it integrates into the Rails project as far as setting up routes, saving content, serving content, etc...Then you can start exploring the source code on Github to see all the internals.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's interesting. I've been able to find some other guides and looking through the source code of this, it looks like I need to do some more study of the Rails basics.